# Extracting data from a POST request in Java

Tags: java, curl, post

When I perform a CURL request to an API endpoint, I'm finding that on parsing the request, the JSON I'm sending is being placed inside request > delegate > body, rather than where I'm expecting in `request.body()`

This is unexpected and as a result ends up with the code below creating a record in the database with a null value.

Do I need to modify the curl request? Or extract the data in some other way?

The CURL request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"christian"}' http://127.0.0.1:4567/suppliers
```

The POST code

```
    post("/suppliers",
            (request, response) -> {

                response.type("application/json");
                Supplier supplier = new Gson().fromJson(request.body(),
                        Supplier.class);

                SupplierCrud sc = new SupplierCrud();
                sc.createSupplier(supplier);

                return new Gson().toJson(new StandardSupplierResponse(
                        StatusResponse.SUCCESS,new Gson().toJsonTree(supplier)));
            });
```

[image: The location the data is stored]

Comment: How is the code that you provided relevant? Doesn't it return the appropriate JSON? Why do you care what the contents of variables are, if you're using a method? Does the method return the correct value or not?

Comment: @RealSkeptic the code is relevant because we can see that the json is getting passed into the endpoint, but crucially not under `body`, which is the only place I (think) I can interrogate with `request.body`. The method never saves the value that is passed into the POST as it isn't retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb. I found that I had made my `Supplier.java` object with capitalised variables.

`@Expose
    private String Type;
    @Expose
    private int Id;
    @Expose
    private String Name;`

I modified this to all lower case. Everything subsequently worked...

`@Expose
    private String type;
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @Expose
    private String name;`